# How to get correct interpolated values in SciPy?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, interpolation

I am using [this data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwwhEMUIYGyTTW44N1ZXZlJrbDg/view?usp=sharing) to obtain interpolated results using SciPy's `InterpolatedUnivariateSpline` but when I plot the interpolated data with original data it seems they are not correctly interpolated. I get interpolated data as shown in fig.:

[image: plot with incorrect interpolation]

***How do I correctly obtain interpolated values in Python with this data?***

**MWE**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy import interpolate
import itertools


data = np.loadtxt('interp.dat', delimiter = '\t')
x = data[:, 0]
y = data[:, 1:]

x_interp = np.linspace(x[0], x[-1], 301)
y_interp = np.empty(shape = (x_interp.shape[0], y.shape[1]))
for i in range(y.shape[1]):
    f = interpolate.InterpolatedUnivariateSpline(x, y[:, i], k = 3)
    y_interp[:, i] = f(x_interp)


fig = plt.figure()
plot = plt.subplot(111)
markers = itertools.cycle(('o', '^', 's', 'v', 'h', '>', 'p', '<'))
for i in range (y.shape[1]):
    plt.plot(x, y[:, i], linestyle = '', marker = markers.next())
    plt.plot(x_interp, y_interp[:, i], linestyle = ':')
plot.set_ylim([0, 200])
plot.set_ylabel('Y')
plot.set_xlabel('X')
fig.savefig('interp.pdf')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `InterpolatedUnivariateSpline` requires increasing `x` points, and yours are decreasing.  From it's documentation:

> x : (N,) array_like
>       Input dimension of data points -- must be increasing

If you reverse your `x`- values with

```
x = data[::-1, 0]
y = data[::-1, 1:]
```

instead of

```
x = data[:, 0]
y = data[:, 1:]
```

it interpolates correctly.  There's still something odd about the data with the highest `y`-values.

Thank you for posting your data; without that it would have been impossible to figure out what's wrong.[image]